Error en campo Fecha/hora al exportar lista SharePoint a Excel
Me ocurre una cosa muy rara. tengo una lista en SP con un campo donde guardo la fecha/hora.
Al exportar esta lista a Excel, este campo de fecha/hora me la carga con dos horas de diferencia.... NO sé si es debido a algún tema de configuración regional del servidor donde está ubicada la lista y mi máquina al exportar a Excel.....
Gracias y un saludo!



Al menos en Excel las fechas son números: la parte entera es la fecha como tal y la parte decimal serían las horas. Es posible que en valor numérico haya alguna diferencia entre ambas y por eso salen las 2 horas de diferencia. ¿Cómo haces la exportación?

utilizando la función que ofrece la Lista...... te descarga un fichero query.iqy que es una consulta para Excel

En SharePoint revisa la zona horario en configuración regional.
Si no en Excel puedes hacer una fórmula para que te sume +02:00:00
